# How to write this sql query in Ruby Join query (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
SELECT rs.id as rs_id,
sum(rs.amount_per_month) as rs_am1,
sum(rs.amount_per_month_per_sqft) as rs_am2,
rs.from_date,rs.to_date,cc.charge_type as cc 
FROM   lease_rent_rolls as lrr 
INNER JOIN leases as l ON  lrr.lease_id = l.id 
INNER JOIN rents as r ON l.id = r.lease_id 
INNER JOIN rent_schedules as rs ON r.id = rs.rent_id 
INNER JOIN charge_codes as cc ON rs.charge_code_id = cc.id 
WHERE lrr.id = 449443 
AND   DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN rs.from_date AND rs.to_date 
GROUP BY cc.charge_type
```

I am using this SQL Query in model using `find_by_sql`, But i should get this same result in Ruby Joins where condition in model without the help of SQL.

Comment: Could you please show us your models as well, including associations between them?

Comment: please share your model association then it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you will provide association then it will be more helpful to provide solution.

Now, I am considering :

LeaseRentRoll has one or many leases.

Lease have many rents.

Rent have many rent_schedules.

and RentSchedule have many charge_codes.

If LeaseRentRoll has one lease:

```
LeaseRentRoll.where(:id => 449443).first.lease.joins(:rents => [:rent_schedules => charge_codes]).select("rent_schedules.id as rs_id, sum(rent_schedules.amount_per_month) as rs_am1, sum(rent_schedules.amount_per_month_per_sqft) as rs_am2,
```

rent_schedules.from_date,rent_schedules.to_date,charge_codes.charge_type as cc")

If LeaseRentRoll have many leases:

```
LeaseRentRoll.where(:id => 449443).first.leases.joins(:rents => [:rent_schedules => charge_codes]).select("rent_schedules.id as rs_id, sum(rent_schedules.amount_per_month) as rs_am1, sum(rent_schedules.amount_per_month_per_sqft) as rs_am2, rent_schedules.from_date,rent_schedules.to_date,charge_codes.charge_type as cc")
```

Please have a look on attached image. It will help to understand more to above query.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
RentSchedule.joins([{:rent => {:lease => :lease_rent_rolls}}, :charge_code]).where("lease_rent_rolls.id = #{lease_rr.id} 
and rent_schedules.from_date < '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")}' 
and rent_schedules.to_date > '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%s")}'").group("charge_codes.charge_type")
```

Got the Result for this Query.Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@goods =Good.joins(:user).where("name like ?", "%#{@searched_good}%").where("category_id = ?", params[:category]).where("postal_code == ?", @searched_good_postal_code)
```

with:
- category_id and name belong to Good array
- postal_code belongs to User array

Comment: Thanks for the post, But m in need of join multiple tables.